# AngularJS: NameError: name is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get error:

```
NameError: name 'resp' is not defined
```

While rendering this `html`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SPA book_store</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script> src = "main.js"</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input id="filter_input" type="text" ng-model="word"/>
    <br/>
    <input id="btn" type="button" ng-click="get()" value="Check Level">
    <br/>
    <label>{{resp}}</label>
</div>
<br/>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js in the same directory with `html` file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.resp= {};
    $scope.get = function() {
        $http.get("https://localhost/" + $scope.word)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.resp = response.data;
                });
    }
});
```

I defined `resp` in controller as scope variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the error message point to any particular line of code…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the mistake I guess. Change this

```
<script> src = "main.js"</script>
```

to

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was also in Python http://stackoverflow.com/a/29293126/3014866

Comment: Ahaaa. Okay got it man :) But I couldn't guess what is your back end tech.